# porting of R code to Python

Tags: python, r, porting

I am looking for a way to port R code to Python.  I wonder if anyone knows of some way to do a rough translation, to facilitate porting.  Note that I am not interested in running R from Python, or Python from R - I want native Python from existing R code.  I have written a few functions in R that translate a few language features automatically:

```
  gsub.R.to.python <- function(x)
  {
        #  very crude conversion of R code to python - facilitating manual port
        out <- gsub.function.to.def(x)
        out <- gsub(pattern = "<-","=",out)
        out <- gsub.dots.to.underscore(out)
        out <- gsub.python.remove.brackets(out)
        out <- gsub.T.to.True(out)
        out <- gsub.F.to.False(out)
        cat(out)
        invisible(out)
  }

  gsub.dots.to.underscore <- function(x)
  {
        #  replace dots to underscores in variable names (i.e. between letters)
        # gsub.dots.to.underscore(c("a.b","1.0")) -->  "a_b" "1.0"
        out <- gsub(pattern = "(?<=[a-zA-Z])\\.(?=[a-zA-Z])","_",x,perl = T)
        return(out)
  }

  gsub.function.to.def <- function(x)
  {
        #  change all function lines - use perl multiline searching
        out <- gsub("(?m)^([a-zA-Z].+?) <- function\\((.+?)\\)","def \\1(\\2):",x,perl = T)
        return(out)
  }

  gsub.python.remove.brackets<- function(x)
  {
        #  get rid of brackets on their own lines
        out <- gsub("(?m)^\\s*\\{\\s*$","",x,perl = T)
        out <- gsub("(?m)^\\s*\\}\\s*$","",out,perl = T)
        return(out)
  }

  gsub.T.to.True <- function(x) gsub("\\bT\\b|\\bTRUE\\b","True",x)
  gsub.F.to.False <- function(x) gsub("\\bF\\b|\\bFALSE\\b","False",x)
```

Running gsub.R.to.python() on a block of R code produces a block of Python-ish gibberish that is a bit easier to translate into Python.  I am looking for a better / more complete version of this idea, or some other tool to help in the porting process.

For example, running this code in R on the code itself, produces the following:

```
  def gsub_R_to_python(x):

        #  very crude conversion of R code to python - facilitating manual port
        out = gsub_function_to_def(x)
        out = gsub(pattern = "=","=",out)
        out = gsub_dots_to_underscore(out)
        out = gsub_python_remove_brackets(out)
        out = gsub_T_to_True(out)
        out = gsub_F_to_False(out)
        cat(out)
        invisible(out)

  def gsub_dots_to_underscore(x):

        #  replace dots to underscores in variable names (i_e. between letters)
        # gsub_dots_to_underscore(c("a_b","1.0")) -->  "a_b" "1.0"
        out = gsub(pattern = "(?<=[a-zA-Z])\.(?=[a-zA-Z])","_",x,perl = True)
        return(out)

  def gsub_function_to_def(x):

        #  change all function lines - use perl multiline searching
        out = gsub("(?m)^([a-zA-Z].+?) = function\((.+?)\)","def \1(\2):",x,perl = True)
        return(out)

  gsub_python_remove_brackets= function(x)

        #  get rid of brackets on their own lines
        out = gsub("(?m)^\s*\{\s*$","",x,perl = True)
        out = gsub("(?m)^\s*\}\s*$","",out,perl = True)
        return(out)

  def gsub_T_to_True(x): gsub("\bT\b|\bTRUE\b","True",x)
  def gsub_F_to_False(x): gsub("\bF\b|\bFALSE\b","False",x)
```

Comment: have you tried [rpy2](http://rpy.sourceforge.net/)?

Comment: rpy2 is calling R from Python, which the op does not want.

Comment: Do you really think that is worth the time? An editor with good python support and a judicious use of snippets will take you a long way.

Comment: I am using pycharm and it is very helpful. The value of a tool such as the one I sketch out above is just to get a headstart on the porting process.  The tradeoff of the time to develop such a tool versus a port without it seems to depend on the amount of code there is to port, and how much of the new code can be made with existing snippets.  I am hoping that someone has built or might build a more comprehensive solution, as there are probably a lot of people who use both R and Python.